# How to parallelize the for loops that calculate matrix elements in R?

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing

I want to calculate elements of a large matrix. In a simple setup the code is like that:

```
sim = Matrix(0, nrow=n,ncol=n, sparse= TRUE)
for (i in 1:n)
  for( j in 1:i)
    sim[i,j] = Somefunction(vec[[i]],vec[[j]])
```

How can I make loops parallel?

Comment: Have a look at https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/#filling-something-in-parallel/.

Comment: If you want a sparse matrix, the best is to return all (i,j,x), and make the matrix later.

Comment: What exactly isn’t working presently? Which result are you getting?

Comment: @F.Privé: thank you, this introduction is so helpful!